# use python library for custom filter analyzer in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

I want to create an `index` for `persian-language` text and I want to create stemmer for that, this is `english-stemming` for `description` field

```
PUT my_index
{
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "description": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "english"
        }
      }
    }, 
    "settings": {
      "analysis":{
        "filter": {
          "english_stemmer": {
            "type":       "stemmer",
            "language":   "english"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Now I want to know how can implement the `PersianStemmer` python library to elasticsearch `analyzer`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create custom analyzer for that:

```
    PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "persian_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "persian"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "persian_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "persian_stemmer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "description": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "persian_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have `PersianStemmer` library for that, but how can I use that on plugin?